# USB2 timeout error

Tags: usb, serial-port, xhci-hcd

I've been having an issue today with connecting some lab equipment to my computer that has worked in the past. Connected through usb, but I cannot see /dev/ttyACM0 as I usually do. /dev/ttyUSB is also missing.

Here is the output of dmesg :

```
[  337.762259] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  342.875314] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  389.345548] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I originally thought it was a permission problem, but I'm leaning now towards an issue with USB configuration or serial access. I'm still very much a noob at this though and if anyone has advice or debugging techniques for this it would be greatly appreciated!

I am running Ubuntu 4.4.0-112-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that shows that the error code came from a lack of power distribution to the instrument. I unplugged everything (usb from laptop, power supply to instrument), shutdown laptop and instrument, and came back 5 minutes later. Everything works again now...

Weird problem, but easy enough solution